# problems in zend framework using jqgrid

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jqgrid

Im trying to use jqgrid in a zendframework project, im trying to fecth the values from a table called utilizadores.
in firebug i am receiving the ok message, but the aswer is this:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Eulen2\application\controllers\UtilizadoresController.php</b> on line <b>51</b><br />
{"page":"1","total":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["hugo silva","admin","Admin"]}]}
```

the line 51 is this:

```
$responce->page = $page > $total_pages ? $total_pages : $page;
```

here is my code:

utilizadores controller action list

```
 public function listAction()
    {
        // action body
        if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
            Zend_Paginator::setDefaultScrollingStyle('Sliding');
            $page = $this->_getParam('page', 1);
            $limit = $this->_getParam('rows', 0);
            $sidx = $this->_getParam('sidx', 1);
            $sord = $this->_getParam('sord', 0);
            $totalrows = $this->_getParam('totalrows', false);
            if($totalrows)
                $limit = $totalrows;
            $employeesModel = new Application_Model_Account();
            $filters = !empty($_REQUEST['filters']) ? (array) json_decode($_REQUEST['filters']) : array();
            //$jqGridModel = new Application_Model_JqGrid();
            $employeesModelSelect = ($_GET['_search'] == 'true') ? $jqGridModel->where($employeesModel, $filters['rules']) : $employeesModel->select();
            $employeesModelSelect->order("$sidx $sord");
            $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($employeesModelSelect);
            $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
            $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page)->setItemCountPerPage($limit);
            $count = count($employeesModel->fetchAll() );
            $total_pages = $count > 0 ? ceil($count / $limit) : 1;
            $responce->page = $page > $total_pages ? $total_pages : $page;
            $responce->total = $total_pages;
            $responce->records = $count;
            $i = 0;
            foreach($paginator as $item)
            {
                $responce->rows[$i]['id'] = $item['id_utilizador'];
                $responce->rows[$i]['cell'] = array($item['nome'], $item['username'],$item['tipo_utilizador']);
                $i++;
            }
            echo json_encode($responce);
        } else
        {
            $this->_helper->layout()->pageTitle = 'Listagem de utilizadores';
            $this->_helper->layout()->pageDescription = 'Neste seção podes listar todos os utilizadores';
        }
    }
```

in my list.phtml i have got this:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $("#toolbar").jqGrid({ 
                caption:"Utilizadores",
                colNames:['Nome', 'Apelido','Cargo'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'nome',index:'nome'},
                    {name:'username',index:'username'},
                     {name:'tipo_utilizador',index:'tipo_utilizaodr'}
                ],
                datatype:"json",
                height:421, 
                rownumWidth:40,
                pager:'#ptoolbar',
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                rowNum:10,
                sortname:'id_utilizador',
                sortorder:'desc',
                url:'/utilizadores/list/',
                viewrecords:true,
                width:740
            });
            $("#toolbar").jqGrid('navGrid','#ptoolbar',{del:false,add:false,edit:false,search:false});
            $("#toolbar").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult:true,searchOnEnter:false});
        });
    </script>
```

and my account model

```
class Application_Model_Account extends Zend_Db_Table
{
 protected $_name = 'utilizadores';
}
```

the connection to the db is working fine, because ive got a login form, and i can acess according to the field existent on the table "utilizadores".

i have tried to substitute the code to return the xml instead of json but the samething happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$responce was not defined before you used it, that is why you get a warning.

Try adding

```
$responce = new stdClass();
```

just before $responce->page ...

Comment: thanks, the warning disappears, but the grid still doesnt show the data..this is the result.{"page":"1","total":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["hugo silva","admin","Admin"]}]}

Comment: it was a mistake by me..the datatype was xml instead of json...thanks for the help...